# jquery to javascript equivalent of a variable containing clone object

Tags: javascript, jquery, clone

```
var board_code_clone = $('#board_code').contents().clone(false);

alert( board_code_clone.filter('div').eq(x).children().eq(y).text() );//make this right
```

i want to have a code equivalent to this

```
$('#board_code_dup > div').eq(x).children().eq(y).text();
```

My intention for this is to have a clone copy of the code they type on #board_code and then i will be trying to manipulate it using board_code_clone and then append the manipulated board_code_clone to the html dom

Comment: Are you asking how to implement the second code block without using jQuery?

Comment: `.contents()` gets way more than just html tag elements. you probably need `.children()` instead.

Comment: @crazy train: not really if there is a jquery equivalent of what im trying to do. i simply wanted to replace #board_code_dup in the second block with board_code_clone variable from the first block to have an equivalent value/process like the 2nd code block

Comment: `board_code_clone.children("div").eq(x).children().eq(y).text()`

Comment: not getting the same value as what would the 2nd code gives me

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding correctly, you can just do your clone, make the modifications and then append back to the DOM, just as you said:

```
// Get the contents
var clone = $('#board_code').contents().clone(false);

// Do your manipulations
var edited = // modify `clone` as necessary

// Append back to the DOM
$('#new_content').append(edited);
```

Comment: substitute '#board_code' to 'clone' in this line of code: $('#board_code > div').eq(x).children().eq(y).text();